# What is the 'React' way to scroll to a certain Component on the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I would like to have a header with links that would scroll to those sections on a page.

Can I somehow achieve this with `refs`? maybe `forwardRef`?

In vanilla JS, I would achieve this with :

```
onClick=(()=>{
            let elm = document.getElementById('experience-head');
            elm.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start',
            inline: 'nearest',
        });
})
```

However, This is the layout of my app:

```
return (
        <FPWrap>
            <Header />
            <SlantDivider id="slant-a" color="black" />
            <About id="about" />
            <SlantDivider color="black" />
            <ExperienceHead id="experience-head" />
             ....
            <Footer />
        </FPWrap>
    );
}
```

Comment: Refs are definitely the "react" way though I've never been able to find a good reason why to use refs in a case like this. They're nice when you don't have control over a component (i.e, a library) as they give you a reliable way to target a specific element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref example:

```
const Component = () => {
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  const executeScroll = () => myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
  return (
    <FPWrap>
      <Header />
      <SlantDivider id="slant-a" color="black" />
      <About id="about" />
      <SlantDivider color="black" />
      <ExperienceHead ref={myRef} id="experience-head" />
      <button onClick={executeScroll}> Click to scroll </button>
      ....
      <Footer />
    </FPWrap>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that code to do the scrolling would be inside of the Header component